# How to set the PATH environment in a Jenkins scriptive pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running this on my local machine's Jenkins installation. I tried this to now avail. The shell command fails since it can't find terrarom executable in `/usr/local/bin`

```
node {
    withEnv(["PATH = /usr/local/bin:$env.PATH"]) {
        // The pipeline will fail it can't find terraform
        stage("Check terraform") { 
            sh "terraform --version"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you install terraform ?

Comment: In [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables), there are no spaces around the `=` using `withEnv`. You also might want to try printing the value of `PATH` in your stage to confirm it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember now if I did with brew or just downloaded the zip file and put it in `/usr/local/bin`, though I think it's the latter.

Comment: @ShaneBishop, that was it, no spaces! Put this as the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables), there are no spaces around the `=` using `withEnv`.

What you want is

```
node {
    withEnv(["PATH=/usr/local/bin:$env.PATH"]) {
        stage("Check terraform") { 
            sh "terraform --version"
        }
    }
}
```